# How do I make all posts that share a category appear on a page in Django

Tags: python, django, categories

How do I make the page list all posts that that share the same category id? I have the category titles as a separate "foreign key" model. My goal is to be able to type in my URL so that I have the category id at the end and it shows me all the posts that have the specific category id.

```
"""models.py"""
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
slug = models.SlugField()

def __str__(self):                           
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-category', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class HelpPage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(default="test")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

"""views.py"""

class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'category'
    template_name = 'blog/categories.html'

"""urls.py"""
from .views import (
CategoryDetailView,)
urlpatterns = [
path('category/<int:pk>', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='post-category'),]

"""categories.html"""
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    Category name: {{ category.name }}
{% for post in category.post_set.all %}
    post: {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

[image: categories.html]

Answer (score 1):

In your DetailView you'll need to capture the category ID passed through urls.py. Here is some info on how to do that:
https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2019/01/django-when-and-how-use-detailview/

Once you have that you can use it to run a query like this to filter for specific posts:

```
HelpPage.objects.filter(category__id=id)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more about how to capture category id. When I researched about that I read that by putting <int:pk> in the url then it captures the id and sends it to the view. But how do I call it in the view? Sorry if that questions seems a little confusing.